# How can I use XMPP in synchronous code with sleekxmpp?

Tags: python, asynchronous, xmpp

I am trying to find a way of using an asynchronous XMPP library in a synchronous function call.

I want to write a simple Python function that sends its arguments via an XMPP message, receive a reply, and return this reply:

```
def read_ans(a,b,c):
    # send [a,b,c] via an XMPP message
    # wait for XMPP message with reply, z
    return z
```

I found the `sleekxmpp` library, and wrote a simple script to do this. The issue I am having is that `sleekxmpp` operates in several threads, and specifies a callback for received messages. I am not sure how to run it synchronously.

What I have so far is below. How can I pass `self.last_message` to `read_ans` so that it can be returned?

Thanks!

```
import sleekxmpp
class XMPP(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):

    def __init__(self, jid, password, myargs):
        sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)
        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start)

        # Store arguments
        self.myargs = myargs

        # This is where we store the last message received
        self.last_message = ""
        self.add_event_handler("message", self.message)

    def start(self, event):
        self.send_presence()
        self.get_roster()

        self.send_message(mto=recipient, mbody=str(self.myargs))

    def message(self, msg):
        if msg['type'] in ('chat', 'normal'):
            #Store the received message
            self.last_message = msg['body']
            self.disconnect()

def read_ans(a,b,c):
    xmpp = XMPP("user", "pass", [a,b,c])            
    if xmpp.connect():
        xmpp.process(block=True)

    # How can I return the message here?
    return '!?!?'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_ans(1,2,3)
```